# Double layer encryption: "Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher..."

Tags: java, encryption

I have an application consisting of three services: *Client*, *Server* and *TokenService*. In order to access data on the *Server*, *Client* has to obtain `SecurityToken` object from *TokenService*. The communication between parties is encrypted using shared keys (*Client* and *TokenService* share a key 'A' and *TokenService* and *Server* share a different key 'B'). When *Client* sends request to *TokenService* then the communication is encrypted with 'A'. When *TokenService* returns `SecurityToken` object, this object is encrypted with B and A like this: `((SecurityToken)B)A)`. This doubly encrypted object first goes back to *Client*, *Client* decrypts it with A, puts it into another object, attaches some additional information (String with request) and sends it to the *Server* where `SecurityToken` gets decrypted with B.

Everything works fine until I'am decrypting `SecurityToken` object on the server side. I get Exception:

```
 javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:749)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:675)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:313)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
at mds.hm5.sharedclasses.Decryptor.decryptData(Decryptor.java:40)
at mds.hm5.tokenservice.Main2.main(Main2.java:28)
```

I was able to recreate this error (without remote communication between parties) like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SecurityToken s = new SecurityToken(false, "2");

    try {
        byte[] bytes = Encryptor.getBytesFromObject(s);
        bytes = Encryptor.encryptData(bytes, "secretkey1");
        bytes = Encryptor.encryptData(bytes, "secretkey2");
        bytes = Base64.encodeBase64(bytes);

        System.out.println(bytes);

        bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(bytes);
        bytes = Decryptor.decryptData(bytes, "secretkey2");
        bytes = Decryptor.decryptData(bytes, "secretkey1");
        SecurityToken s2 = (SecurityToken) Decryptor.getObjectFromBytes(bytes);

        System.out.println(s2.getRole());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**I have no idea what I'am doing wrong here. Is it impossible to create two layers of encryption just like that? Am I missing something?**

*Additional information:*

Here is my Encryptor class:

```
public class Encryptor {

public static byte[] encryptData(byte[] credentials, String key){

    Cipher c;
    SecretKeySpec k;
    byte[] byteCredentials = null;
    byte[] encryptedCredentials = null;
    byte[] byteSharedKey = null;

    try {

        byteCredentials = getBytesFromObject(credentials);
        byteSharedKey = getByteKey(key);

        c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        k = new SecretKeySpec(byteSharedKey, "AES");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);
        encryptedCredentials = c.doFinal(byteCredentials);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return encryptedCredentials;

}

public static byte[] getBytesFromObject(Object credentials) throws IOException{

    //Hmmm.... now I'm thinking I should make generic type for both: Token and ITU_Credentials object, that would have this getBytes and getObject methods.
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutput out = null;
    byte[] newBytes = null;

    try {

      out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
      out.writeObject(credentials);
      newBytes = bos.toByteArray();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      out.close();
      bos.close();
    }
    return newBytes;
}

private static byte[] getByteKey(String key) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException{

    //Converting key to SHA-1 and trimming to mach maximum lenght of key

    byte[] bkey = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
    MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    bkey = sha.digest(bkey);
    bkey = Arrays.copyOf(bkey, 16);

    return bkey;
}
```

And here is my Decryptor class:

```
public class Decryptor {


public static byte[] decryptData(byte[] encryptedCredentials, String key){

    Cipher c;
    SecretKeySpec k;
    byte[] byteSharedKey = null;
    byte[] byteObject = null;


    try {

        byteSharedKey = getByteKey(key);

        c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        k = new SecretKeySpec(byteSharedKey, "AES");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, k);
        byteObject = c.doFinal(encryptedCredentials);



    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return byteObject;

}

public static Object getObjectFromBytes(byte[] credentials) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{

    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(credentials);
    ObjectInput in = null;
    ITU_Credentials credentialsObj = null;

    try {

        in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        credentialsObj = (ITU_Credentials)in.readObject(); 

    } finally {
      bis.close();
      in.close();
    }
    return credentialsObj;
}


private static byte[] getByteKey(String key) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException{

    //Converting key to SHA-1 and trimming to mach maximum lenght of key

    byte[] bkey = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
    MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    bkey = sha.digest(bkey);
    bkey = Arrays.copyOf(bkey, 16);

    return bkey;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Encryptor();
}
```

}

**EDIT:**

As advised, I replaced all `e.printStackTrace();` with `throw new RuntimeException(e);` in the `Decriptor` class to properly throw exceptions:

```
public class Decryptor {


public static byte[] decryptData(byte[] encryptedCredentials, String key){

    Cipher c;
    SecretKeySpec k;
    byte[] byteSharedKey = null;
    byte[] byteObject = null;


    try {

        byteSharedKey = getByteKey(key);

        c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        k = new SecretKeySpec(byteSharedKey, "AES");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, k);
        byteObject = c.doFinal(encryptedCredentials);



    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return byteObject;

}

public static Object getObjectFromBytes(byte[] credentials) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{

    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(credentials);
    ObjectInput in = null;
    ITU_Credentials credentialsObj = null;

    try {

        in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        credentialsObj = (ITU_Credentials)in.readObject(); 

    } finally {
      bis.close();
      in.close();
    }
    return credentialsObj;
}


private static byte[] getByteKey(String key) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException{

    //Converting key to SHA-1 and trimming to mach maximum lenght of key

    byte[] bkey = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
    MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    bkey = sha.digest(bkey);
    bkey = Arrays.copyOf(bkey, 16);

    return bkey;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Encryptor();
}

}
```

Now the exception looks as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
at mds.hm5.sharedclasses.Decryptor.decryptData(Decryptor.java:51)
at mds.hm5.tokenservice.Main2.main(Main2.java:28)
Caused by: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:749)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:675)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:313)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
at mds.hm5.sharedclasses.Decryptor.decryptData(Decryptor.java:40)
... 1 more
```

Comment: Please get rid of those `e.printStackTrace();` things and properly rethrow the exceptions (you should exit after an exception occurs). The final exception might just be a followup...

Comment: @femtoRgon I'am sorry I just edited it.

Comment: @home: Should I just replace all `e.printStackTrace()` with `Sytem.exit()` ?

Comment: For testing purpose just replace it with e.g. `throw new RuntimeException(e)`, so your application will immediately exit after an exception occured (and print the stacktrace). After that check if your stacktrace changes...

Comment: @home: Thanks, I will remember to do it properly in the future. Unfortunately, In this case it didn't show me much. Now I'am getting _...RuntimeException : IllegalBlockSizeException_...  Caused by: _IllegalBlockSizeException_...

Comment: @Booyaches: thanks for trying. this was just to make sure there were no (strange) side effects. It might make sense to edit your question and add the updated code (including stacktrace), so that we're all on the same page.

Comment: Try modifying Encryptor to match, and I think you may see something different, as indicated in my answer.

Comment: @femtoRgon I modified Encryptor but it did't show me anything new. However, I can see your point in your answer. I will investigate it now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the root of your problem is:

```
byte[] bytes = Encryptor.getBytesFromObject(s);
bytes = Encryptor.encryptData(bytes, "secretkey1");
```

which goes to:

```
//etc.//
byte[] encryptedCredentials = null;
byte[] byteSharedKey = null;

try {
    byteCredentials = getBytesFromObject(credentials);
    //Whoops!  credentials is already a byte array.
//etc.//
catch (and eat) exception.....
return encryptedCredentials;
```

And, since you eat the exception and just return null, as home has advised against in the comments, then it keeps moving until it gets to the decryption step, where it throws an exception you hadn't anticipated (when it fails to decrypt, an IllegalBlockSizeException which is none of the eight types of Exception that you catch there), and gives you something useful.

That's what I think is going on anyway.